# jquery slider moving off viewport

Tags: jquery

hello I made this slide show - I want the ul to stop moving once it reaches the last/first image of the list.

This is what I have so far.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".prev").click(function(){
            $(".slider-list").animate({
                left: "-=604px",
            });
        });
    });  

               $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".next").click(function(){
            $(".slider-list").animate({
                left: "+=604px",
                stop:200,

            });
        });
    });
```

thanks

Comment: and the stopping part? where did you try ?

Comment: it didnt do anything, i tried to change it to stop: "200px" ; to see if it would stop at 200px  from the left? but nothing

Comment: you need to make a counter and track the current slide and stop if its the last or the first

Comment: mmm how would i go about doing that?

Comment: first you create a variable, increase/decrease  that variable on click of next/prev, test if that variabile is 0 or max to stop the slider, easy

Comment: ok cheers i'll have a go